# How can I send my Vec to a function taking an Iterator as a parameter?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, borrowing

I have an issue where I've got a function that takes in an `Iterator` of a specific struct type, and I want to send in my Vector that contains this same struct-type as a parameter to the function.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have tried several different things:

- Sending the `vecName.iter()` leaving me with this `error: error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving <std::slice::Iter<'_, code_test_lib::gfx::AsteroidDrawData> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == code_test_lib::gfx::AsteroidDrawData`
- Sending the `vecName.into_iter()` leaving me with this `error: error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content`
- Sending the `&vecName.iter()` giving me this `error: error[E0277]: &std::slice::Iter<'_, code_test_lib::gfx::AsteroidDrawData> is not an iterator`
- Sending the `&vecName.into_iter()` giving me this: `error[E0277]: &std::vec::IntoIter<code_test_lib::gfx::AsteroidDrawData> is not an iterator`

I don't know how I can send the `Vec` to the function as an `Iterator`.

```rust
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub dataA: f32,
    pub dataB: f32,
}

struct MyProgram {
    my_structs: Vec<MyStruct>,
}

pub trait BaseFunctions {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn run(&mut self);
}

impl BaseFunctions for MyProgram {
    fn new() -> Self {

        //Create some data
        let mut vec = Vec::new();
        for x in 0..5 {
            vec.push(MyStruct{
                dataA: 1.0,
                dataB: 1.0,
            });
        }

        Self {
            my_structs: vec,
        }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {

        my_func(
            self.my_structs.into_iter(),
        );
    }
}

pub fn my_func<Iter>(iter: Iter)
where
    Iter: Iterator<Item = MyStruct>, {
        for i in iter {
            // Do something
        }
}


fn main() {
    let mut program = MyProgram::new();
    program.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `iter()` generate an `Iterator` on reference not on the value. So you need to have a reference and a lifetime to your function. It's better to make a bound on [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) that allow more generality.

```rust
pub fn my_func<'a, Iter>(iter: Iter)
where
    Iter: IntoIterator<Item = &'a MyStruct>,
{
    for i in iter {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Call like this `my_func(&self.my_structs);` or `my_func(self.my_structs.iter());`

Comment: Thanks, Stargateur! That did the trick! Sorry for the first confusing code example!